# get a child name from Firebase Database Progmatically

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase database i have a directory called `Global_downloads` then inside there are a few children.

child.("Casting apps") which i can locate with in my app code using a String value called AppType.

the next child.("All cast") is the child i need. i can get it into firebase by using an onitem click with my listview. which then sends it to firebase in the form of a child.

but how can i locate the name for the child(Allcast) progmatically? so i can then get the number of downloads?

[image]

here is my code for my child listener

```
@Override
public void onChildAdded(final com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
String counter = dataSnapshot.child("Global_downloads").child(Apptype).
            child("I need this child").child("downloads").getValue(String.class);
    Downloadscount.add(counter); 

String[] arr3 = Downloadscount.toArray(new String[Downloadscount.size()]);
```

the rest of the items in the constructor are for other items in my listview

```
///my custom adapter where it returns the info to my listview
apkData = new dataListAdapter(mContext, arr, arr1, arr2,  mrootRef, Apptype,arr3);
  mlv.setAdapter(apkData);
        apkData.notifyDataSetChanged();


  mlv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            final Firebase ref = mrootRef.getRef();

//here is where i assign the name to firebase in my counter class which works
            apkNames = AppNameList.get(i).toString();  //this is the name i want to send back to the top and use as a Child name.or can i get the child name another way.
 gc = new Global_counter(ref,Apptype,apkNames);
            gc.App_DownLoadCounter();
```

this is my listview there are more items on my list other than Allcast.
but all cast is the only item downloaded. if more items are pressed it adds that name to the list too. the text view you can see is the downloads im trying to add

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the coresponding item that was downloaded, please use the following line of code inside `onItemClick()` method and then just use it inside your `DatabaseReference`.

```
String downloadName = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

Assuming that `Global_downloads` node is a direct child of your Firebase root and the value of `downloads` is of type `Integer`, to get the number of downloads please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference downloadsRef = rootRef.child("Global_downloads").child(Apptype).child(downloadName).child("downloads");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int downloads = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
        Log.d("TAG", downloads);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
downloadsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
0
```

Comment: Sorry Alex there are other items in the list All cast is the only item downloaded.. if another item is downloaded it will add that item as well. ill add ascreen shot of how my list view looks

Comment: Are you displaying those names (All cast and so on) in a ListView?

Comment: yes alex but i dont know the child name until on item is fired. it always returns null.

Comment: i get a null string aschild. this is because untill an item is clicked there is null value for downloadName im also not using a value event listener im using a a Child event listener as there are a few items per list item. these include a pic an about and url.

Comment: When you are clicking an item and you are using `String downloadName = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);` what is the value of downloadName?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159707/discussion-between-markharrop-and-alex-mamo).

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, the key is `Apptype` and the value is `downloads`.
I'm assuming `Global_dowbloads` under your `root` reference.

To get all the downloads with app name, you need to read the data as `key->value`

Like this

```
DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mRef.child("Global_downloads").child(Apptype)
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            Log.v("app_name", snapshot.getKey());
                            Log.v("app_downloads", snapshot.getValue(String.class));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: this is how ive done it. but im using a childevent listener. the only problem i face now is that it add a new  item to my list view. with the download value. this happens untill i close the app and restart. im assuming its that i need to resend the dat back to my list adapter.

Comment: You need to create an app **download model class** on your android project and add _attributes_ in it. Then you only need to pass the list of **download models** to your array adaptor to display the data (also compatible with real-time data handling)

Comment: download model?

Comment: if we add more attributes to the apptype node, then you would need to create the class model (a java class having the same structure as the attributes under your apptype node) to get the value from data snapshot.

Comment: have u got an example of this @Hassnain

Comment: [here I attached an image](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-jZJxlZvXGuI/Whl8anT0ndI/AAAAAAAAADY/zn5xTSFQvQwXKb4U5BkYxipfhHVAw845QCLcBGAs/s1600/Screenshot_1.png) then in the data snapshot get it as your data model type.